# "Four-part" composition of characters

Tags: characters

I would like to compile a list of characters where you can draw two lines in a + shape, running through the center of the character to cleanly separate it into four "components." Some leeway must be given when writing them.

For example, 疑, 殺, and 豔 fit my criteria. For 疑, I wouldn't call ヒ or マ Chinese real Chinese characters, but they are Japanese katakana so they must be related (maybe historically) to Chinese. So the character qualifies to me. I only studied traditional characters so there could be even more simplified ones.

I'm not even sure if there's a term for this type of character geometry. There might be a workbook somewhere that has collected such characters.

Comment: [Origin of Katakana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#History) :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I accidentally wrote hiragana :( Shame on me

Comment: I actually didn't notice that. But good. :P I was giving to you the history of the signs, so you can see where they come from. :)

Comment: This is really off-topic and off-language, but I have to mention the absurdity of マ being derived from = when 疑 clearly contains it.

Comment: Japanese katakana's were Chinese characters used to show pronounciation, but later simplified to smallest significant parts in terms of efficiency. I myself also found that in writing practice, sometimes you can synthesize a pile of strokes (totally different) into a sign with its recognizable feature. Maybe that is something that makes Chinese handwriting personal and where the art of caligraphy begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a list for characters with distinct components - I imagine that will be pretty hard to define precisely - but there are indeed lists for characters with "repeated" components （同字合体字, or 疊字)

[On Wikipedia](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E5%8F%A0%E5%AD%97), there is a list for words with four repeated components (for interest only - most of these characters are not used in daily settings).

Comment: Nice! The only one I've seen is 4 dragons. Yeah, I might have asked a bad question, because it really depends on how many characters a person knows. I've asked language teachers and they had no suggestions. So I came to the pros here in Stack Exchange :)

Answer (score 5):

here some data i managed to compile. it's a bit of a mess, so pls bear with me:

---

## http://bbs.whnews.cn/simple/index.php?t133800.html

品字结构：
鑫森淼焱垚品晶瞐畾矗聶众劦叒尛姦磊孨森蟲譶赑馫雥飍飝毳骉犇羴贔龘皛轟麤靐厽垚壵惢歮皛羴骉驫鱻卉芔灥厵猋舙掱晿刕嚞雥䨺㐂䆐䖃  灥厵叒
田字结构：
燚茻㵘䲜㗊䨻㸚㠭朤叕
三叠字：
雦㴇 㙓㐺渁隻雙䨇 巛彡巜十卄卅卌廿嬲 嫐  奻
左右上下叠字：
吅吕昍昌目䀠炎炏从仌厸㕕双㕛騳多奻㚣誩弜㯤喆屾出
上下叠字：
爻戔哥棗畕圭亖
左右叠字：
囍 孖夶㹜犾㚘㯥皕豩牪龖虤聑朋臸㱛砳玨甡祘竝覞賏踀辡秝兟兢競竸槑雔抙䬕䎜㐩㒭㚁㲎㿟 䡛玆㐨絲㣈㚡㒹㽬䪭兓幵艸斦比羽

## http://culchina.net/bbs/dispbbs.asp?boardID=6&ID=10236&page=1

一二三亖、七㐂、十卄卅卌、廿、人从仌众㐺、金鑫、木林森、水沝㴇淼㵘、火炎炏焱燚、土圭垚㙓、士壵、豕豩、牛牪犇、牟、羊羴、馬騳骉驫、、犬㹜犾猋、鹿麤、龍龖龘、虎虤、屮艹艸芔、虫蟲、魚鱻䲜、鳥 隹雔雦雥、飛飝、习羽、古、吉喆嚞、毛毳、口吅吕品㗊、舌舙、耳聑聶、手抙掱、舌、白皛、日昍昌晶、、月朋朤、明 、目䀠瞐、至臸、女奻姦、男、了、子孖孨、山岀出屾、石砳磊、泉灥、刀刕、力劦、心惢、戈戔、百皕、玉玨珏、風䬕飍 、雷靐䨻、雲䨺、厶厸㕕厽、又双㕛叒叕、乂爻㸚、田畕畾、生甡、示祘、立竝、香馫、原厵、見覞、言誩譶、貝賏贔、足踀、車轟、辛辡、糹絲、至臸、禾秝、止歮、大夶、小尛、少、无兓、先兟、克兢、竞競、竟竸、呆槑、干幵、可哥、弓弜、工㠭、个、門、面、牙、齒、文、甲、乙、亦、永、僉、斤斦、兀、且、串、凡、卤 、直矗、喜囍、善、東㯥、朿棗、束、秦䆐、若䖃、夏、春、空、客、寒、宝、舍、県、夕多、户 、启、支、果、比、盖、秉、竹、老䎜、興、來㯤、函、歹㱛、幽、隻雙䨇、井㐩、兄㒭、尭㚁、、旡兂、卪、㔾

或

一二三亖、四、七㐂、九、十卄(niàn)卅卌(xì)、廿、人从仌众㐺、金鑫、木林森、水沝(zhuǐ)㴇淼㵘、火炎炏(yán)焱(yàn)燚(yì)、土圭垚㙓、士壵(zhuàng)、豕(shǐ)豩(bīn)、牛牪(yàn)犇(bēn)、牟、羊羴(shān)、兔、馬騳(dú)骉(biāo)驫、犬㹜犾猋(biāo)、鹿麤(cū)、龍龖(dá)龘(dá)(zhé)、虎虤(yán)、屮(cǎo)艹(cǎo)艸芔(huì)卉、虫蟲(chóng)、魚鱻(xiān)䲜、鳥隹(zhuī)雔(chóu)雦(jí)雥(zá)、飛飝(fēi)、飞、习羽、古、吉喆(zhé)嚞(zhé)、毛㲎毳(cuì)、口吅(xuān)吕品㗊、舌舙(huà)、耳聑(zhé)聶、手抙掱(pá)、舌、白㿟皛(pò)、日昍(xuān)昌晶、月朋朤、明、目䀠瞐(mò)、至臸(zhī)、女奻(nuán)㚣姦、男、了、子孖(mā)孨(nì)

山岀出屾(shēn)、石砳(lè)磊、泉灥(xún)、原厵(yuán)、刀刕(lí)、力劦(xié)、心惢、戈戔(jiān)、百皕(bì)、玉玨(jué)珏(jué)、風䬕飍(xiū)、雷靐(bìng)䨻(bèng)、雲䨺、厶(sī)厸(miǎn)㕕厽(lěi)、又双㕛叒(ruò)叕(zhuó)、乂爻㸚、田畕(jiāng)畾(léi)、生甡(shēn)、示祘(suàn)、立竝(bìng)、香馫(xīn)、見覞(yào)、言誩(jìng)譶(tà)、貝賏(yīng)贔(bì)、頁、足踀(cù)、車䡛轟、辛辡(biàn)、禾秝(lì)、止歮(sè)、大夶(bǐ)、小尛(mó)、少、老䎜、先兟(shēn)、克兢(jīng)、竞競(jìng)、竟竸(jìng)、呆槑(méi)、干幵(jiān)、可哥、弓弜(jiàng)、工㠭、个、門、面、牙、齒、文、甲、乙、亦、永、僉(qiān)、斤斦(zhì)、兀、且、串、凡、卤、直矗、喜囍(xǐ)、善、東㯥、朿棗、束、秦䆐、若䖃、夏、春、客、寒、空、宝、宜、妥、盖、舍、県、斗、市、太、天、興、光、企、果、秉、竹、夕多、户、尸、启、支、比、或、来來㯤、去、函、歹㱛、幽、隻雙䨇、井㐩、兄㒭、尭㚁、巜、玄玆、予㐨(xù)、㣇㣈、糹(jiǎo)絲(sī)、幺、奇㚡、倉、入、号、巾、巢、左、臣、易、昔、欠、母、禺、尹、真㒹、夫㚘、畐㽬、音䪭、囚、因、困、全、几、凡、句、區、彐、、、㔾、旡兓(jīn)、卪、、、巿(pó)、桼(qī)、兂、㖖(niè)、、眉、

## http://www.xiaohui.com/weekly/20070305.htm

记得当年读初中刚学英语时，常说“我是中国人，不会学外文”，借此来嘲笑那些学英语发狠的同学。哈哈，对头，咱们是中国人，学就应该学中国汉字。不过，既然大家都是中国人，嘿嘿，那么，列在本文 《你认识这些三叠字和四叠字吗? —— 三叠字与四叠字大全》 http://www.xiaohui.com/weekly/20070305.htm 页面中这些字，你认识几个?

```
鑫 森 淼 垚 焱 靐 晶 卉 芔 轟 磊 畾 厽 馫 飍 灥 厵 犇 猋 赑 贔 蟲 麤 毳 龘 骉 驫 羴 雥 鱻 矗 姦 舙 瞐 聶 品 掱 叒 惢 譶 劦 壵 众 孨 歮 晿 飝 刕 尛 嚞 皛 雦 朤 燚 叕 茻
```

上面这些字是我今天收集整理的汉字三叠字与四叠字大全。三叠字，又叫品字型汉字，指由三个完全相同的字叠成“品”字形而形成的新字；四叠字，指由四个完全相同的字叠成“田”字形而形成的新字。
汉字三叠字与四叠字大全

收集整理这个东西，缘起今天下午的时候，在网上看到一个三个牛字叠起来的 犇字，一时想不起起读音，后来一问才知道读 bēn，与奔一个意思， 三头牛一起跑当然就是奔了。貌似以前有个演戏的就叫牛犇。在网上一搜，关于三叠字的介绍有不少，但是没有一个完整的整理集合。维基百科上分别有一个三叠字和四叠字的词条，但数据不全(注: 完成此文后，我在维基百科上更新了此词条)。于是把字典搬出来，借助网络，把所有的三叠字和四叠字找了出来，并注明读音和释义。

一、三叠字列表(共52个)
　　http://www.xiaohui.com/weekly/20070305.htm

1.
      首先我查的就是与五行相关的三叠字: 金木水土火：
         1. 三金鑫 xīn 多用于商店字号、人名用字,取其金多兴旺之意
         2. 三木森 sēn 本义: 树木丛生繁密
         3. 三水淼 miǎo 会意。从三水。又作“渺”。本义:水大的样子。这个字多用作女孩子的名字，我邻居小孩就叫淼淼。:)
         4. 三土垚 yáo 意思为山高，那么多土当然山高啦。多用于人名。古同“尧”。
         5. 三火焱 yàn 光华,光焰。
   2.
      还有一些跟自然植物有关系的三叠字:
         1. 三雷靐 bìng 雷声
         2. 三日晶 jīng 从三日,表示光亮之意
         3. 三屮卉（芔） huì 会意。小篆字从三“屮”(chè),草木初生。本义:草的总称
         4. 三车轟 hōng 同“轰”,会意。从三车。本义:群车行驶声
         5. 三石磊 lěi 众石，石头多,心地光明坦白
         6. 三田畾 léi 古同“雷”，同“垒”，也表示田间的土地
         7. 三厶厽 lěi 垒土块为墙
         8. 三香馫 xīn 古同“馨”,芳香,散布很远的香气
         9. 三风飍 xiū 惊跑的样子
        10. 三泉灥 xún 三泉
        11. 三原厵 yuán 古同“源”,水源,源泉
   3.
      跟动物有关的三叠字:
         1. 三牛犇 bēn 同奔。有个人的名字叫“牛犇犇”，小名叫“七匹牛”。:)
         2. 三犬猋 biāo 狗奔跑的样子。同“飙”
         3. 三贝赑(贔) bì传说中的一种动物,像龟。旧时大石碑的石座多雕刻成赑屃形状
         4. 三虫蟲 chóng 同虫
         5. 三鹿麤 cū 同“粗”
         6. 三毛毳 cuì 会意。从三毛。本义:鸟兽的细毛
         7. 三龍龘 dá 这个是刚才去台湾维基查词条时发现的。《广韵》说该字之义为“龙飞之状”；《说文》解作“飞龙”。成语：龍行龘龘。龘字是现时大五码编码(big5)当中笔划最多的一个字，共48划。

```
     8. 三马骉(驫)piāo 众马奔腾的样子
     9. 三羊羴 shān 古同“膻”,也表示群羊。另外是鼻烟品目之一。
    10. 三隹雥 zá 群鸟；聚
    11. 三鱼鱻 xiǎn 古同“鲜”
```

4.
      下面是跟人物有关的:
         1. 三直矗 chù 会意。从三直。本义:直立
         2. 三女姦 jiān 会意。从三女。本义:奸邪,虚伪狡诈
         3. 三舌舙 huà 播弄是非。古同“话”。
         4. 三目瞐 mò 美目; 目深; 美丽的样子
         5. 三耳聶 nie 会意。从三耳。本义:附耳小语。这么多耳朵凑在一块，当然是咬耳朵说私语了。
         6. 三口品 pǐn 会意。从三口。口代表人,三个表多数,意即众多的人。
         7. 三手掱 pá 俗称扒手为三只手,故写作“掱”。掱手 = 扒手。哈哈，这个很形象。
         8. 三又叒 ruò 古同“若”
         9. 三心惢 suǒ 疑虑；善
        10. 三言譶 tà 说话快
        11. 三力劦 xié 古同“协”，合力；同力。
        12. 三士壵 zhuàng 古同“壮”, 本义:人体高大,肌肉壮实
        13. 三人众 zhòng 人三为众
        14. 三子孨 zhuǎn 谨慎；弱，懦弱；孤儿
   5.
      其他
         1. 三止歮 sè 古同“涩、澁”
         2. 三日晿 chēng 古人名用字. 注意这个字与晶字不同。

```
        附注：在本文评论的第12楼、第14楼中，一位叫蓝昊的朋友认为“晿 ”字的底部，不是日字，而是一个曰字。我查证了一下，认为他说得有道理。不过由于没有翻到权威的证据，估且仍列在这里。

     3. 三飞飝 fei
     4. 三刀刕 lí 姓氏
     5. 三小尛 mó 古同“麽”，细小，微细
     6. 三吉嚞 zhé 古同“哲”,聪明,有智慧
     7. 三白皛 xiǎo 皎洁，明亮
     8. 三隹雦 chóu 古同“集”, 群鸟在木上也
```

四、四叠字列表(共17个)
　　http://www.xiaohui.com/weekly/20070305.htm

除了三叠字，还有四叠字。顾名思义，四叠字由四个完全相同的字叠成“田”字形而形成的新字。目前计算机系统能够显示四个四叠字，其余的已经被 Unicode 标准收录，但现在的系统和字库还没有支持，所以不能够被显示。

1.
      计算机能够显示的四叠字
         1. 四月朤 lǎng 古同“朗”。本义:明亮。四个月亮当空照，不明亮都没天理了。:)
         2. 四火燚 yì 火貌
         3. 四又叕 zhuó 连缀,短；张网的样子
         4. 四屮茻 mǎng 众草；丛生的蕨类

## http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/三叠字

三叠字
三叠字是指汉字中一类由三个完全相同的字叠成“品”字形而形成的叠字。现将已知的此类字列于下表：

[编辑] 漢字中的三疊字

以下標示的為汉语拼音。

```
* 鑫 拼音：【Xīn】發音同：【音】注音：【ㄒㄧㄣ】
* 森 拼音：【Sēn】發音同：【蔘】
* 淼 拼音：【Miǎo】發音同：【秒】
* 焱 拼音：【Yán】發音同：【炎】
* 垚 拼音：【Yáo】發音同：【搖】
* 犇 拼音：【Bēn】發音同：【奔】
* 驫,骉 拼音：【Biāo】發音同：【飆】
* 羴 讀音：【Shān】發音同：【杉】
* 猋 拼音：【Biāō】發音同：【飆】
* 麤 拼音：【Cū】發音同：【粗】
* 鱻 拼音：【Xiān】發音同：【鮮】
* 蟲 拼音：【Chóng】發音同：【崇】
* 贔, 赑 拼音：【Bì】發音同：【毙】
* 众 （「眾」的簡化字） 拼音：【Zhòng】發音同：【仲】
* 品 拼音：【Pǐn】發音同：【品】
* 掱 拼音：【Pá】發音同：【爬】
* 劦 拼音：【Xián】發音同：【协】
* 晶 拼音：【Jīng】發音同：【精】
* 磊 拼音：【Lěi】發音同：【壘】
* 姦 拼音：【Jiān】發音同：【奸】
* 聶 拼音：【Niè】發音同：【涅】
* 毳 拼音：【Cuì】發音同：【脆】
* 矗 拼音：【Chǔ】發音同：【觸】
* 飝 拼音：【Fēi】發音同：【飛】
* 刕 拼音：【lí 】發音同：【离】
* 厽 拼音：【Lěi】發音同：【垒】
* 叒 拼音：【ruò】發音同：【若】
* 壵 拼音：【Yáo】發音同：【搖】
* 尛 拼音：【Má】發音同：【麻】
* 孨 拼音：【zhuǎn】發音同：【转】
* 歮 拼音：【sè】發音同：【涩】
* 惢 拼音：【suǒ】發音同：【所】
* 皛 拼音：【xiǎo】發音同：【晓】
* 畾 拼音：【léi】發音同：【雷】
* 嚞 拼音：【zhé】發音同：【哲】
* 舙 拼音：【huà】發音同：【hua】
* 譶 拼音：【tà】發音同：【踏】
* 雥 拼音：【zá】發音同：【杂】
* 灥 拼音：【xún】發音同：【寻】
* 飍 拼音：【xiū】發音同：【修】
* 馫 拼音：【xīn】發音同：【興】
* 厵 拼音：【yuán】發音同：【员】
* 靐 拼音：【bìng】發音同：【雷】
* 龘 拼音：【dá】發音同：【踏】
* 赑 拼音：【bì】發音同：【闭】
```

[编辑] 三疊字的功能

1) 表示加三倍的東西之獨特：

鑫 xin1 (很富的，越來越大的豐富) 姦 jian1 (姦淫) 猋 biao1 (快) 鱻 xian1 (鮮) 惢 suo3 (善) 瞐 mo4 (美目的) 麤 cu4 (粗)

2) 集合概念：

驫 / 骉 biao1 (馬群) 羴 shan1 (羊群) 磊 lei3 (堆) 垚 yao2 (堆) 众 zhong4 森 sen1

2) 小的與多有的：

毳 cui4 (鸟兽的细毛 / 寒毛) 晶 jing1 (本指星星，現代表示光亮) 蟲 chong2 (蟲子)

4) 誇大：

掱 pa2 (偷) 譶 ta4 (说话快) 舙 hua4 (说是非话) 猋 biao1 (狗奔) 聶 nie4 (附耳小语) 叒 ruo4 (若 （用又［手］表明方法） 飍 xiu1 (惊跑) 犇 ben1 (奔)

正常表示用什麽身體的部分動作的偏旁，這爾是加三倍的，又是用長的寫法的。表示誇大的行爲。

5) 比較級：

矗 chu4 (矗立的) 尛 mo2 (微小的) 皛 xiao3 (喧)

6) 加三倍表現狀況或者景象：

轟 hong1 (三輛車相撞） 品 pin3 （三個箱子） 厽 lei3 (垒) 畾 lei2 雷 (鬼魂頭) 淼 miao3 (水面)

## http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/二叠字

二叠字，也稱爲雙叠字，指汉字中一类由三个完全相同的字組成的叠字。

表示加倍的東西之獨特

昍 xuān (明) 吅 xuān (喧)

這個功能很稀少的，因此我們認爲例外。三叠字為這個功能更常見的。

[编辑] 加倍指肯定的狀況

奻 nuán (争吵) 夶 bǐ (比) 从 cóng (跟随) 誩 jìng (争论)

與三叠字的第四功能很近。這爾的只是更象形的，和跟三叠字相反不是誇大的。

[编辑] 表示東西雙倍地存在

孖 zī (双生子) 皕 bì (二百) 斦 yín (二斤、公斤、千克) 双 shuāng 二 èr

[编辑] 集合的概念

林 lín (森林)

森林是樹木的集合，如同一群是牛或似的動物的集合。 雖然森林的使用跟群的不同的。

經常用三叠字為這個功能。

## http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/四叠字

四叠字

四叠字是指汉字中一类由四个完全相同的字叠成“田”字形而形成的叠字。现已知的此类字共17個，列于下表：

[编辑] 汉字中的四叠字

```
* 叕 讀音：【茁】 拼音：【zhuó】
* 朤 讀音：【亮】 拼音：【liàng】
* 燚 讀音：【一】 拼音：【yī】
* 茻 讀音：【蟒】 拼音：【mǎng】
* 㠭 (四個工) 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
* 㵘 (四個水) 讀音：【漫】 拼音：【màn】
* 㗊 (四個口) 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
* 㸚 (四個乂) 讀音：【麗】 拼音：【lì】
* 叕 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
*  (四個人) 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
*  (四個厶) 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
*  (四個日) 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
*  (兩個比) 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
*  (四個田) 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
*  (四個竹) 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
*  (四個金) 讀音：【】 拼音：【】
* 䨻 (四個雷) 讀音：【蹦】 拼音：【bèng】
*  (四個龍) 讀音：【哲】 拼音：【zhé】
* 䨻 (四個雲) 讀音：【農】 拼音：【nóng】
* 䨻 (四個興) 讀音：【正】 拼音：【zhèng】
```

28cc8     #25115112
200db

6b63    正   #12121
23944     #12121

821b    舛
5905    夅

20141

上下

【辰集下】【止字部】  ·康熙筆画：4　·部外筆画：0

【唐韻】【集韻】他達切，音撻。【說文】蹈也。从反止。轉注。本作。　與少別。【佩觿集】少，申兆翻，不多也。，他末翻，蹈也。步字从此。【集韻】作。原从反止，類似从反正。

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1309/16), there's [a WikiCommons project](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Chinese_characters_decomposition) to describe the composition of Chinese characters. If you search that table for entries with 叕 in the third column, you'll find a few, including 叕, 朤, and 燚. If you want to find characters with four different components arranged that way, then you'll probably have to do some coding. You'd have to find all characters that have 吅 in the third column, and then both components have 吕. There might be some in the opposite order, as well.