# How Many Characters Are There Where The Radical Is The Same As The Main Component?

Tags: characters

- How Many Characters Are There Where The Radical Is The Same As The Main Component?

Example:

[字海网: ](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=E686)

> [image: o]

[字海网:](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=2767F)

> [image: o]

This question is definitely answerable as there are only a certain amount of radicals.

Comment: Here is one: 冰 (ice) both parts mean water.

Comment:  (钅金) is a SunmanPUA character incase anyone is wondering.

Comment: Does 朋 count, ？

Comment: there are also 从，林

Comment: if you extend the search over repetitious characters, there are *many* more

Comment: Note that 从 only works in simplified Chinese, so, combined with the fact that characters are well, "simplified", answers will be dependent on whether traditional or simplified characters are used.

Comment: @Maroon not quite right, as the line between 'simplified' and 'traditional' characters is somewhat blurry, cf. 网, which is really the original pictograph used for later 網, and, likewise, 从 is the original form of 從. The latter one is used throughout the 說文解字.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick perusal of my database gives me

```
u-cjk/6299      抙  ⿰扌手
u-cjk/726a      牪  ⿰牜牛
u-cjk/72be      犾  ⿰犭犬
u-cjk/73cf      珏  ⿰王玉
u-cjk/8aa9      誩  ⿰言言
u-cjk/8e00      踀  ⿰足
u-cjk-xa/3908   㤈  ⿰忄心
u-cjk-xb/201a7    ⿰亻人
u-cjk-xb/23c99    ⿰氵水
u-cjk/9342      鍂  ⿰金金
```

(considering only Unicode code points). I tested against the RegEx `氵水|礻示|⺬示|釒金|钅金|王玉|忄心|竹|讠言|言言|冫氷|扌手|足|⻗雨|爫爪|亻人|火灬|犭犬|牜牛|飠食|食|饣食`, which may be incomplete.

In related news, a search for `水水|示示|金金|王王|玉玉|心心|竹竹|手手|足足|雨雨|爪爪|人人|火火|犬犬|牛牛|食食` brings up, amongst others, these:

```
u-cjk/4ece      从  ⿰人人
u-cjk/6c9d      沝  ⿰水水
u-cjk/708f      炏  ⿰火火
u-cjk/73a8      玨  ⿰王王
u-cjk/7958      祘  ⿰示示
u-cjk-xa/3e5c   㹜  ⿰犬犬
u-cjk-xb/225f0    ⿰心心
u-cjk-xb/22a92    ⿰手手
u-cjk-xb/24519    ⿱爪⿰爪爪
u-cjk-xb/24934    ⿰玉玉
u-cjk-xb/25d12    ⿱竹⿰竹竹
```

some of which may violate your expectations about how to correctly write characters, as the usual positional variants are not used in these forms.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you are looking for a list of such characters in Simplified Chinese. There is probably more, but here you go.

**Notes**

- I added extra lists just for completeness. Feel free to add to it!
- By "non-radical" I mean the identical parts are not a radical themselves.

---

- **Top-bottom Radical Pair**

> 炎、多、昌、二、亖、畕、仌、歨（not 走）

- **Left-right Radical Pair**

> 林、双、从、朋、赫、竝、孖

- **Top-down Non-radical Pair**

> 出、哥、爻、串

- **Left-right Non-radical Pair**

> 囍、吕、二、羽、兢、非、弱

- **Three-character/radical Words**

> 淼、鑫、焱、垚、森、众、磊、品、晶、羴、鱻、犇、厽、惢、掱、聶、姦、畾、尛、孨、毳、蟲、麤、猋、骉、龘、赑、轟、矗、嚞、芔、歮、雥、叒、皛、馫、靐、飍、飝、刕、譶、毳、劦、舙、厵、灥

- **Four-character/radical Words**

> 燚、朤、茻、叕

Comment: btw there's a looooong list of these @ http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/5353/3674

Comment: @flow Hmm, I'm profoundly impressed by your effort.